# bootstrap form add div by clicking add button

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where I would like my users to add max 3 of languages skills and languages levels. I would like to only show it one and let user click to add one more (add one more "profile2" div, max add 3). I did not find anyway to do it.

my html code:

```
      <div class="container">
    <div class="profile2">
         <label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language</label>
<select class="form-control bfh-languages" data-language="en" id="sel1"> </select>
<label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language Level</label>
<select class="form-control" data-language="en" id="sel1">
<option>Basic</option>
<option>Fluent</option>
<option>Professional</option>
<option>Native</option>
 </select>
 <button id="btnAddLanguage" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">Add Language</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

script

```
    <script>
 $("#btnAddLanguage").click(function () {
      $('#container').append("<div class="profile2">
         <label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language</label>
<select class="form-control bfh-languages" data-language="en" id="sel1"> </select>
<label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language Level</label>
<select class="form-control" data-language="en" id="sel1">
<option>Basic</option>
<option>Fluent</option>
<option>Professional</option>
<option>Native</option>
 </select>
 <button id="btnAddLanguage" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">Add Language</button>
    </div>");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268564/adding-dropdown-list-to-new-row-on-button-click

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need ? please check this.

```js
<script>
$("#btnAddLanguage").click(function () {
 var $appendItem = $('.profile2').html();
  $($appendItem).appendTo('.profile2');
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="profile2">
  <label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language</label>
  <select class="form-control bfh-languages" data-language="en" id="sel1"></select>
  
  <label for="sel1" class="langlevel">Language Level</label>
  <select class="form-control" data-language="en" id="sel1">
    <option>Basic</option>
    <option>Fluent</option>
    <option>Professional</option>
    <option>Native</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btnAddLanguage" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">Add Language</button>
</div>
```

Comment: From your code is it basically what I need to do but I copy the exact code and it is still not working